# MongoDB copy object while changing parameters

Tags: mongodb, insert, find

In Mongo, what's the best way to copy a record while changing a property on it?

For example say I have a user object and I want to copy it while changing some properties.
So (logically):

```
db.users.find({_id:"Fred"}).forEach( function(r) { db.users.insert(r.copy("_id"="Barney","age":25)) } );
```

Of course there is no "copy" function, but that's what I'm looking for: a way to copy a document, while changing some properties (of course the key _id).

Comment: Depends on the programming language/framework -- generally speaking, just save the document again, with a new `_id` (or clear it and let the DB handle it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to copy anything, for example this will work just fine:

```
db.users.
    find( { _id: "Fred" } ).
    forEach( function (r) { 
        r._id = "Barney"; 
        r.age = 25;
        db.so.insert( r );
    } );
```

I don't quite understand why you would want to do it like this though. It makes much more sense to just insert a new document with all the original fields again for the new "Barney" document.